# Two aggregate funcitons with different criteria

Tags: oracle, case, aggregate

I like to use two aggregate functions (`COUNT`, `SUM`) in one SQL statement with the help of `CASE WHEN` Statement. My code is like this:

```
CASE
      WHEN    (   (   (   (   (CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.ORDER_TYPE = 'OR')
                           OR (OCSSC_MASTER_VIEW.ORDER_TYPE = 'KB'))
                       OR (CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.ORDER_TYPE = 'KE'))
                   OR (CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.ORDER_TYPE = 'OR-TAT'))
               OR (CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.ORDER_TYPE = 'QT-TAT'))
           OR (CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.ORDER_TYPE = 'QT')
      THEN
         COUNT((CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.ORDER_LINE_NUMBER))

      ELSE
         SUM((CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.ORDER_LINE_NUMBER))
   END
      AS Lines_processed
```

This code gives an error "Oracle Database Error: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement"

Could any one help me on this?

Comment: We need the full statement in order to help you. Also why do you use so many parentheses? Do you deliberately try to make your code harder to read/debug?

Comment: I think you're going to have to split that into two separate aggregates.  At the moment, you're asking for the impossible: two values in a single output.  What is the database to return -- the SUM or the COUNT?  It can't tell; neither can I.

Comment: As Jonathan points. It seems you are aggregating but there can be some rows that match one case and some that match the other case. What should be done then? Count or Sum?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the double ( ) in

```
((CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.ORDER_LINE_NUMBER))
```

and

```
SUM((CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.ORDER_LINE_NUMBER))
```

oh and

```
CASE WHEN (CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.ORDER_TYPE IN ('OR', 'KB', 'KE', 'OR-TAT', 'QT-TAT', 'QT'))
  THEN COUNT(CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.ORDER_LINE_NUMBER)
  ELSE SUM(CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.ORDER_LINE_NUMBER)
END
AS Lines_processed
```

Should work too

Comment: Thanks but it is resulting in another error " Oracle Database Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function". Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: You're probably missing the group by clause

Answer (score 0):

It looks like how you nested the expressions in the WHEN clause is what's killing you; try getting rid of all parentheses in that statement

EDIT: Or, better yet, use an IN statement like vc 74 suggested.